# How to get sensor measurement and capture image from camera simultaneously in android?

Tags: android, camera, android-sensors

I want to capture the sensor readings at the exact time when an image is captured in android.

I know to get sensor values. I also know to capture images from camera intent.

But the problem is that the sensor values may not correspond to the exact time of capture. This is because the camera app has the user delay for the "OK/cancel" thing after clicking an image.

How do I obtain the sensor reading at the exact time of clicking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> *But the problem is that the sensor values may not correspond to the exact time of capture. This is because the camera app has the user delay for the "OK/cancel" thing after clicking an image.*

When user clicks an image, you can observe the image folder for file changing, then you know exact time.